# Freelancers, do you have any advice when clients cancel the project?

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites

I joined a website design project for a client. I asked him to deposit 50% of the project's money. 
I sent draft designs; they were almost complete. Suddenly, the client said he met a financial problem and canceled the project. 
We didn't sign any contracts. I couldn't get the remaining amount while I think I deserve more than the 50% deposit. How do you handle cancellations?

Comment: This seems apropos - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEa6PdOG2ts

Answer (score 1):

With no contract, keep the 50% and move on.

If you want a "kill fee" you need to have that in a contract. It's difficult, if not impossible, to try and collect a cancellation fee *after* cancellation without something in writing. You can certainly *ask* for such a fee. But the client has no obligation to pay anything.

In addition, it's *your* responsibility if the deposit does not adequately cover the work needed prior to client review.